# Setting up Live @ EDU

Tags: email, exchange, cloud

[PROBLEM]

Hello everyone.  I have a small issue here.  We are trying to get our exchange accounts for students only ported over from an exchange server 2003 to the Microsoft cloud services known as live @ EDU.  The problem we are having is that in order to do this we need to install 2 pieces of software

1: OLSync
2: Microsoft Identity Life cycle Manager

"Download the Galsync.msi here"  the "Here" link takes you to a page that needs a login for an admin account for live @ EDU.  That part works.  However once logged in it redirects to a page that states:

https://connect.microsoft.com/site185/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=26407

Page Not Found

The content that you requested cannot be found or you do not have permission to view it.

If you believe you have reached this page in error, click the Help link at the top of the page to report the issue and include this ID in your e-mail: afa16bf4-3df0-437c-893a-8005f978c96c

[WHAT I NEED]

I need to download that file.  Does anyone know of an alternative location for that installation file?  I also need to obtain Identity Lifecycle Management (ILM) Server 2007, Feature Pack 1 (FP1).

If anyone has any helpful information that would be fantastic!  As well if anyone has completed a migration of account from a on site exchange 2003 server to the Microsoft Live @ EDU servers any general guidance would be helpful!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From [this site](http://outlookliveanswers.com/forums/t/5482.aspx):

1. Sign in to Service Management Portal  <<https://eduadmin.live.com>> with your domain admin credentials.
2. Click on the "Single sign-on" option. This will open the "Single sign-on support" page.
3. click on the "Download Microsoft Live@Edu SSO kit" link on the page. This will take you to the Connect site.
4. If this is your first time logging into Connect, you might have to Register yourself.
5. Once the registration is complete, you will reach the "Microsoft Live@edu Home" page on Connect.
6. Click on the "Downloads" link in that page, and a list of downloads will be displayed